# Looping through multiple sheets in excel using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop through mutiple sheets in my workbook. I have a "sheet 1", "sheet 2", and then I have sheets named "Version 1" to "Version n". I want to loop through all the version sheets. So I am writing a for loop but it keeps giving me an "Object Required" error. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Below is my code. I am starting at 3 because I don't want to loop through sheet 1 or sheet 2.

**The sht = Sheet.Count row is giving me "Object Required error"**

```
Sub LoopThroughSheets()
Dim a As Long, sht As Long
sht = Sheet.Count
    For a = 3 To sht
  
    Next a
End Sub
```

Comment: pls try Sheets.Count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly loop through your worksheets and only run the code if your `Sheet.Name` includes "Version*"

***Modified Code***

```
Sub LoopThroughSheets()

Dim sht As Worksheet

For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sht.Name Like "Version*" Then
        ' rest of your code goes here
    
    End If
Next sht
    
End Sub
```